# In react while using function ,it's property not showing on screen

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am learning React-JSX and I have tried a code

```
function sayHello(){
  return <h1>Haiiiiii</h1>
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <sayHello> Haiiiiii </sayHello>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

*Haiiiiii* is rendering to screen but the `<h1>` heading format is not showing on screen.(ie.,*Haiiiiii* is not showing in bold font )

Comment: Where do you set it as a bold font?

Comment: I want to display it as what an <h1>tag  is supposed to display a text

Comment: Make the component name as `SayHello` (capital S), also all the children will be passed in props so write it like this: `function SayHello(props){
   return (
    <h1>
     Haiiiiii
     {props.children}
    </h1>
 )
}`

Comment: Yes . It worked when capitalized the component name

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing

```
function sayHello(props){
  return <b>{props.text}</b>
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <sayHello text="Haiiiiiiii" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```